# Can i speed up webpack bundling with react on development?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I know this question in very stupid but i am new in this awesome js/react world, so plese, forgive me.

On my project i use react in frontend and django on a server side.
Because on this moment i cant use react routing, i forced to use django routing and include webpack bundles into html files.

So when i develop i do this steps:
1. write code on javasxript/react
2. yarn run webpack --config someconfig.js

So, this bundling propcess takes a very long time. Can i do something to bypass bundling process or speed up it on development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure babel-loader uses cache and doesn't transpile `node_modules`:

**webpack:**

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        cacheDirectory: true,
      },
    },
  },
],
```

**.babelrc**

```
"presets": [
    ["env", { "modules": false }],
    "react",
],
```

Other than that there are some plugins that [aim to speed up](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hard-source-webpack-plugin) rebundling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the webpack-dev-server and have a process running that will look for changes and rebuild.

https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/

This will go over developing including talking about the webpack-dev-server. You might also want to take a look at https://browsersync.io/ so that you can be able to have the browser automatically refresh on a new bundle being available.